# How to get previous row data by using SQL?

Tags: sql, procedures

here is the table example

---

main_CD    code
1            aa

1         bb

1         cc

2         1231

2         1232

### .

that table have lots of data. but i will only use which main_CD is "1"
(other data for other pages I cannot delete it)

my question is that If i got value of "cc".
I want to sent pre_data ("aa") and next data ("cc")

also if i got value of "cc", pre_data would be "bb" and next_data would be "aa"

Comment: You need a column in the table that tells you what row comes before the another row. Do you have that?

Comment: You say you want a stored procedure (for some reason). Which dbms are you using? (Many different stored procedure flavors out there...)

Comment: Use the `lag()` and `lead()` functions

Comment: How do you know that aa is before bb and that cc is after bb? It looks that way to us as humans, but in a database the order of rows is not determined unless you define it explicitly. Are there columns that you've not mentioned?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?